# Python giving issue in opening files

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner to Python so I was trying to learn how to open a file.
I wrote the code below

```
test_file = open('C:\Users\Harsh\Desktop\Anything\RoR.txt')
text = test_file.read()
print(text)
```

But it is giving me this error

```
File "C:\Users\Harsh\Desktop\CODING\Python\testing.py", line 1
    test_file = open('C:\Users\Harsh\Desktop\Anything\RoR.txt')
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add "encoding" , 'r' is for raw text

```
test_file = open(r"C:\folder\file.txt",encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped but could you please explain why do we need to add r

Comment: @TSPR810 It has to do with escaping. For example, `"\n"` represents a newline character, and how would you expect `"D:\name"` to be the same as `"D:\\name"`?

Comment: I do understand but now when I try to write it shows error. How to write to files?

Comment: text_write = open('some_file.txt', 'w')
text_write.write(lines_with_text)
text_write.close()